# Writing to an existing table in docx using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I use POI-3.14 and the [*setText()*](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) method of XWPFRun doen't seem to work. I've tried both *setText(java.lang.String value)* and *setText(java.lang.String value, int pos)*. New text doesn't appear in the table at all.

I need to set text only in the first column of the table.

Here's the code:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(document));

List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables();  

//Output stream 
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {
    List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
    for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells().get(0); 
        for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
           for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
               r.setText("new", 0);
           }
        }
    }
 }
   doc.write(out);
   out.close();
```

**UPD:** When I add FileOutputStream to the same file, then call doc.write(out) I get multiple exceptions. And then the original file becomes empty.

Exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:160)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:215)
    at controller.FileProcessor.process(FileProcessor.java:56)
    at controller.MainController.translate(MainController.java:66)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:214)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.XMLStreamReader.fillByteBuffer(XMLStreamReader.java:209)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.XMLStreamReader.reset(XMLStreamReader.java:97)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.DocumentEntity.open(DocumentEntity.java:94)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.reset(PiccoloLexer.java:982)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:709)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3479)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:92)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.PropertiesDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties.<init>(POIXMLProperties.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:158)
    ... 65 more
```

Creating temporary file for FileOutputStream gives the same result. Only now both the original and the temporary file are empty.

Comment: Are you saving the document? Have you tried printing out the contents of each cell?

Comment: @jontro Yes, I've sucessfully printed out the contents of each sell. But I don't get what and where should I save? XWPFDocument?

Comment: @jontro Or do you mean creating new FileInputStream to the same file and the writing XWPFDocument to it? Could I even do it with the same file?

Comment: You need to call [XWPFDocument.write(OutputStream)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) when you're done making changes, to actually save them to disk!

Comment: @Gagravarr I get multiple exceptions doin just that. See my updated post

Comment: Are you trying to write to the same file, or a different one? If the same, try writting to a different one - in-place write support isn't finished

Comment: @Gagravarr I've tried writing both to the same and a different files. I get the same exceptings either way.